# Restoring Operating System & Preloaded Apps on Dell Laptop 

Tags: windows-7, windows, reinstall, dell-studio, windows-7-restore

I got a virus on my computer and wanted to do a complete re-install on my computer. I got the re-installation disk provided when I first got the computer. I had three partitions OEM, Recovery, and OS, i deleted the Os and created a new on and installed windows on that partition. after everything windows comes up no program. I put in the drivers disk and there was only 3 drivers? that i installed from it. I have no wifi capabilities, all of the default programs when I first got my laptop are on there, nothing.  How do i get my computer back to then point when i originally got it? or at least how to get the wifi, webcam, bluetooth all to work again? Thank you

Comment: Go to www.dell.com. Go to their support section. Put in your laptop model and OS. Download and install the drivers.

Comment: Or use the service tag on the bottom.

Comment: Service tag is best, it will only return drivers for that specific hardware build.

Answer (score 2):

The recovery partition is Dell's recommended way of recovering your computer. While your computer is booting up hold down the F8 key. Amongst the option will be one to 'Boot to recovery partition (sometimes it says 'recovery mode'). Boot into this partition and you will be given a chance to install a factory-placed image of your computer roughly comparable to when you first got it out of the box.